# How to split a string preserving empty elements?

Tags: java, split

When splitting `"TEST/TEST/".split("/")` I will get a string array of `length = 2`.

How can I split getting `length = 3` with elements `["TEST", "TEST", ""]`, thus the last element being empty string?

(I want to achieve this with native Java, and with regards to performance as the split has to take place on a few million rows one after the other).

Comment: As per the Javadoc it will truncate trailing separators if you don't provide a limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parametrize the number of desired array elements with a `split` overload:

```
String input = "TEST/TEST/";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("/", 3)));
// or: input.split("/", -1)
```

**Output**

```
[TEST, TEST, ]
```

**Notes**

- Escaping the forward slash is not necessary
- The "performance" part of your question is a little hard to answer unless you provide more details
- You might want to multi-thread your procedure. In Java 7, you could use the [fork/join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework
- As [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) points out, you can use a negative `int` to apply the pattern...

> as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

(from [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)).

Comment: Or simply use negative limit `split(delimiterRegex, -1)`

Comment: @Pshemo nice one! Will add to the answer.

Comment: @Pshemo great, that's probably best solution to my question.